# Selecting the Hello World Message By Its HTML Tags with the URL Request?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

The URL Request:

```
http://localhost:1430/Home/TheMessageView
```

Also:

```
http://localhost:1430/Home/TheMessageView/{Parameter}
```

Home is the controller.
TheMessageView is the view (as a VBHTML file type).

The HTML Tags with Its Content:

The to be called up messages are held in a View as follows:

```
<h2>The Hello World Message Headline</h2>    
<p>This Hello World message in the paragraph here.</p>
```

The Question:

**Reformulated:**
The intention is to narrow it down till to the preferred HelloWorld message by selecting the HTML tag. Where the message is to be printed on the screen.

Comment: This is a pretty confusing question. The parameter part is where you have your curly brackets in your example. Depending on how your controllers and routing tables are configured is where the parameters go. What kind of app is this, MVC? WCF? In your current mark up, your paramter won't show up anywhere.

Comment: It is for MVC 4 (Visual Studio 2012). For further clarification do imagine it as a "Hello World" message to be printed. The intention is to narrow it down till to the HTML tag and have the message printed. And that, with the URL request. - (I have edited the title of the question.)

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is little confusing but,

Try using

```
Html.Encode("MessageHtml")
```

And try passing it to corresponding url.

Comment: I reformulated the question. The intention was basically to narrow it down to the preferred HelloWorld message by selecting the HTML tag. So the preferred HelloWorld message can be printed on the screen.

Comment: http://localhost:1430/Home/TheMessageView/?param=helloworld

on view page <%: Request["param"]%>

Comment: Is the "helloworld" assigned to an `attribute`?

Comment: I do suspect the request command has to be assigned to the HTML tag, so it can be selected right through the URL request. Whereas I may have preferred a HTML tag selector, similar to CSS.